# MySQL Error: Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query I am fetching three columns (say A,B and Summary)

Summary is based on B and A.

I have to use a subquery to fetch Summary based on A and B.

**Problem:**

For one value of A (say A1) and one value of B (say B1), I get two values of Summary (say Summ1 and Summ2) in One column.

**Hence it gives Error:**

```
 Subquery returns more than one row
```

Instead I want to show it as below in my table:

```
 A1     B1     Summ1
 A1     B1     Summ2
```

How can I do so?

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT a.FundIDRecv,a.SubscribeDt, b.FundName, 
(
   SELECT c.PricePerWeek
   FROM tbl_Hive c
   WHERE c.FundID IN 
   (
      SELECT FundID from tbl_FundStatic 
      WHERE FundID IN
      (
          SELECT FundIDSend
          FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions 
          WHERE FundIDRecv = a.FundIDRecv

      )
      AND UserID = '14'
   )
) as Price
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a, tbl_Hive b
WHERE a.FundIDRecv = b.FundID

AND a.FundIDRecv
IN (

SELECT FundIDRecv
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions
WHERE FundIDSend
IN (

SELECT FundID
FROM tbl_FundStatic 
WHERE UserID = '14'
)
)
Group by a.FundIDRecv
```

SELECT statement for `c.PricePerWeek` generates that error

Comment: show us your query that generates the error.

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: @Nathan,Dobiatowski,Sachin: I have posted my query.

Comment: I think You will have a huge performance problems if tbl_Hive gets bigger. That's because You are using a subquery in a WHERE clause and event worse, it's nested.

Comment: @Piotr Salaciak: So what can be done to avoid the potential performance problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to restructure it as a JOIN rather than a subquery.

Comment: @David Winant: Thanks for your input. How can I do so? Can you help me? I am not sure on how to do that?

Comment: Try the following:  `SELECT a.FindIDRecv, a.SubscribeDt, c.FundName, c.PricePerWeek
  FROM tbl_Hive c
  INNER JOIN tbl_FundStatic b ON c.FundID = b.FundID
  INNER JOIN tbl_FundSubscriptions a ON c.FundID = a.FundIDSend
  WHERE b.UserID = '14'`
It looks like you have 3 tables, and I'm guessing that the PK for FundStatic is FundID+UserID, but what is it for FundSubcriptions and for Hive?

Comment: For fundSubscription it is FundIDSend+FundIDRecv and for Hive it is FundID

Comment: I had a typo in the original, by try the following:

Comment: I had a typo in the original, but try the following:
 
`SELECT a.FundIDRecv Recv, 
       DATE_FORMAT(a.SubscribeDt,'%d %b') SubsDate,
       a.FundIDSend Send, 
       c.FundName Name, c.PricePerWeek PPW
  FROM tbl_Hive c 
  INNER JOIN tbl_FundStatic b 
        ON c.FundID = b.FundID 
  INNER JOIN tbl_FundSubscriptions a 
       ON c.FundID = a.FundIDSend 
  WHERE b.UserID = '14';`

Comment: With my simple sample data, it gives:
`
+------+----------+------+---------+--------+
| Recv | SubsDate | Send | Name    | PPW    |
+------+----------+------+---------+--------+
|    1 | 16 Mar   |   11 | Fund 11 | 99.120 |
|    2 | 16 Mar   |   11 | Fund 11 | 99.120 |
|    3 | 16 Mar   |   10 | Fund 10 |  0.145 |
|    1 | 16 Mar   |   10 | Fund 10 |  0.145 |
+------+----------+------+---------+--------+
`

If that doesn't match what you want, perhaps you could explain what each of the tables is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use subquery to sum column A and B.

just try

```
SELECT A,B,(A+B) as 'sum'
FROM table
```

Post your query to help you more.

**UPDATE**

in your query it is normal that in subquery result return more than one row, maybe you wanted to do it like that: `SUM(c.PricePerWeek)`

```
SELECT a.FundIDRecv,a.SubscribeDt, b.FundName, 
(
   SELECT SUM(c.PricePerWeek)
   FROM tbl_Hive c
   WHERE c.FundID IN 
   (
      SELECT FundID from tbl_FundStatic 
      WHERE FundID IN
      (
          SELECT FundIDSend
          FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions 
          WHERE FundIDRecv = a.FundIDRecv

      )
      AND UserID = '14'
   )
) as Price
....
```

Comment: It is not summation. Please read the whole question. How summation of two numbers can lead to more than one result?

Comment: Also check out the Query. I have added the query to my Question.

Comment: No This is not what I want to do. I dont want Sum of PricePerWeek. I dont want to sum the values `Summ1` and `Summ2` infact I want two different rows to show `Summ1` and `Summ2` as discussed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your subquery in the from clause and try....

Try this...

```
 SELECT a.FundIDRecv,a.SubscribeDt, b.FundName, d.price

FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a, tbl_Hive b,
(  

  SELECT c.PricePerWeek as Price   FROM tbl_Hive c   
   WHERE c.FundID IN  
   (  
      SELECT FundID from tbl_FundStatic
       WHERE FundID IN     
        (
             SELECT FundIDSend
             FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions ,tbl_FundSubscriptions a 
             WHERE FundIDRecv = a.FundIDRecv
        )
        AND UserID = '14' 
 )

 ) d


 WHERE a.FundIDRecv = b.FundID 
 AND a.FundIDRecv IN ( 
 SELECT FundIDRecv FROM   tbl_FundSubscriptions
 WHERE FundIDSend IN 
 (
      SELECT FundID 
      FROM tbl_FundStatic
      WHERE UserID = '14' 
 )
 )
 Group by a.FundIDRecv
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I see it like this:

```
SELECT
  a.FundIDRecv,
  a.SubscribeDt,
  b.FundName,
  b.PricePerWeek as Price
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a, tbl_Hive b
WHERE a.FundIDRecv = b.FundID
  AND a.FundIDRecv IN (
    SELECT FundIDRecv
    FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions
    WHERE FundIDSend IN (
      SELECT FundID
      FROM tbl_FundStatic 
      WHERE UserID = '14'
    )
  )
Group by a.FundIDRecv, b.PricePerWeek
```

The old-fashioned join syntax I would probably replaced by the currently standard one. Also there seems to be one redundant IN subselect.

So eventually the script might look like this:

```
SELECT
  a.FundIDRecv,
  a.SubscribeDt,
  b.FundName,
  b.PricePerWeek as Price
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a
  INNER JOIN tbl_Hive b ON a.FundIDRecv = b.FundID
WHERE a.FundIDSend IN (
  SELECT FundID
  FROM tbl_FundStatic 
  WHERE UserID = '14'
)
Group by a.FundIDRecv, b.PricePerWeek
```