# mysql subquery returns more than 1 row error but that's what I want

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a select like this:

```
SELECT product.*, customers.*, product,id AS productid, (SELECT comment FROM notes WHERE product_id = productid) AS notes FROM products JOIN customers ON customers.product_id = product.id WHERE product.export = 0
```

It gives a error in the subquery for the notes, but I don't want to limit them to 1 I want to get unlimited notes for this product. Is this possible? And how? Or do I need to do a new query for each product to get the notes?

Comment: Can you provide info on your database schema and the exact information you want from your database

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: Subquery returns more than one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324555/mysql-error-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query result can be seen as a grid of cells divided in rows and columns. Each of those cells can only contain one value. But what you can do, is combine all the values of the sub-query into a single value using an aggregation function like `GROUP_CONCAT`. `GROUP_CONCAT` will return all the notes as a single string of text.

```
SELECT product.*, customers.*, product,id AS productid, 
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(comment) FROM notes WHERE product_id = productid) AS notes 
FROM products JOIN customers ON customers.product_id = product.id 
WHERE product.export = 0
```